# How to solve an Integral analytically using a predefined definition for Besselfunctions (phi part of angular spectrum representation)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, physics, optics

I'd like to use mathematica to calculate an Integral that is dependent on phi and theta (to obtain the intensity distribution of a tightly focused TEM20 mode using the angular spectrum representation).
Using the definition $\int_0^{2\pi}cos(n\phi)\cdot e^{ixcos(\phi-\psi)}d\phi=2\pi\cdot i^n
\cdot J_n(x)cos(n\psi) $

,the phi part of the integral should be analytically solvable, while I have to numerically solve the remaining integral over theta.

Mathematica seems to know the above mentioned relation when I just write:

```
Integrate[Cos[p]*E^(I*x*Cos[p - q]), {p, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

or even when I use an integer for n (but not if I write it for a general n), 
and when I ask him to integrate the whole expression, it only returns my input.

I don't know if it helps but the whole expression would be:

```
-1/o^2 0.25 E^(I k z Cos[theta] + I k r Cos[nphi- phi] Sin[theta] - (
f^2 Sin[theta]^2)/o^2) e0 Sqrt[Cos[theta]] (1 - Cos[2 phi] (1 - Cos[theta]) + Cos[theta]) (-2 f^2 + 4 o^2 - 2 f^2 Cos[2 phi] + 
 f^2 Cos[2 (phi - theta)] + 2 f^2 Cos[2 theta] + 
 f^2 Cos[2 (phi + theta)]) Sin[theta]
```

where everything besides phi, nphi and theta are parameters.
Does anyone know what I could do to make this work? I'm quite new to mathematica and would appreciate any help! :)

Comment: Indeed `Integrate[Cos[n p] E^(I x Cos[p - q]), {p, 0, 2 Pi}]` returns unevaluated, since it doesn't know your closed form (altho it should be noted that this is only valid for integer values of `n`).

Comment: I've tried that but it didn't change anything..